# How can I find the elapsed business hours between two dates using pandas' CustomBusinessHour objects?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, relativedelta

If I want to find the number of hours between two `datetime` objects, I can do something like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
day_after_tomorrow = datetime(2022, 9, 24)

diff = (day_after_tomorrow - today).total_seconds() / 3600
print(diff)
```

which returns: `37.58784580333333` hours.

But this is the number of **real hours** between two dates. I want to know the number of **specific business hours** between two dates.

I can define two `CustomBusinessHour` objects with `pandas` to specify those business hours (which are 8AM to 4:30PM M-F, and 8AM to 12PM on Saturday, excluding US Federal holidays):

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessHour
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

business_hours_mtf = CustomBusinessHour(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar(), start='08:00', end='16:30')
business_hours_sat = CustomBusinessHour(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar(), start='08:00', end='12:00')
```

My understanding is that `CustomBusinessHour` is a type of `pandas` `DateOffset` object, so it should behave just like a `relativedelta` object. So I should be able to use it in the `datetime` arithmetic somehow, to get the number I want.

And that's as far as I was able to get.

What I think I'm struggling to understand is how `relativedelta`s work, and how to actually use them in `datetime` arithmetic.

Is this the right approach? If so, how can I use these `CustomBusinessHour` objects to get an accurate amount of elapsed business hours between the two dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. It feels ugly and hacky, but it seems to work. Hopefully someone else has a simpler or more elegant solution.

***Edit***: I cleaned up the documentation a little bit to make it easier to read. Also added a missing kwarg in `business_hours_sat`. Figuring this out was a headache, so if anyone else has to deal with this problem, hopefully this solution helps.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessHour
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

business_hours_mtf = CustomBusinessHour(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar(), start='08:00', end='16:30')
business_hours_sat = CustomBusinessHour(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar(), weekmask='Sat', start='08:00', end='12:00')

def get_business_hours_range(earlier_date: datetime, later_date: datetime) -> float:
    """Return the number of business hours between `earlier_date` and `later_date` as a float with two decimal places.
    
    Algorithm:

    1. Increment `earlier_date` by 1 "business hour" until it's further in the future than `later_date`.
    2. Also increment an `elapsed_business_hours` variable by 1.
    3. Once `earlier_date` is larger (further in the future) than `later_date`...
        a. Roll back `earlier_date` by one business hour.
        b. Get the close of business hour for `earlier_date` ([3a]).
        c. Get the number of minutes between [3b] and [3a] (`minutes_remaining`).
        d. Create a timedelta with `elapsed_business_hours` and `minutes_remaining`
        e. Represent this timedelta as a float with two decimal places.
        f. Return this float.
    """

    # Count how many "business hours" have elapsed between the `earlier_date` and `later_date`.
    elapsed_business_hours = 0.0
    current_day_of_week = 0
    while earlier_date < later_date:
        day_of_week = earlier_date.isoweekday()
        
        # 6 = Saturday
        if day_of_week == 6:
            # Increment `earlier_date` by one "business hour", as specified by the `business_hours_sat` CBH object.
            earlier_date += business_hours_sat
            # Increment the counter of how many "business hours" have elapsed between these two dates.
            elapsed_business_hours += 1
            # Save the current day of the week in `earlier_date`, in case this is the last iteration of this while loop.
            current_day_of_week = day_of_week

        # 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, ...
        elif day_of_week in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
            # Increment `earlier_date` by one "business hour", as specified by the `business_hours_mtf` CBH object.
            earlier_date += business_hours_mtf
            # Increment the counter of how many "business hours" have elapsed between these two dates.
            elapsed_business_hours += 1
            # Save the current day of the week in `earlier_date`, in case this is the last iteration of this while loop.
            current_day_of_week = day_of_week
    
    # Once we've incremented `earlier_date` to a date further in the future than `later_date`, we know that we've counted
    # all the full (60min) "business hours" between `earlier_date` and `later_date`. (We can only increment by one hour when using
    # CBH, so when we make this final increment, we may be skipping over a few minutes in that last day.)
    #
    # So now we roll `earlier_date` back by 1 business hour, to the last full business hour before `later_date`. Then we get the
    # close of business hour for that day, and subtract `earlier_date` from it. This will give us whatever minutes may be remaining
    # in that day, that weren't accounted for when tallying the number of "business hours".
    #
    # But before we do these things, we need to check what day of the week the last business hour is, so we know which closing time
    # to use.
    if current_day_of_week == 6:
        ed_rolled_back = earlier_date - business_hours_sat
        ed_closing_time = datetime.combine(ed_rolled_back, business_hours_sat.end[0])
    elif current_day_of_week in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
        ed_rolled_back = earlier_date - business_hours_mtf
        ed_closing_time = datetime.combine(ed_rolled_back, business_hours_mtf.end[0])
    
    minutes_remaining = (ed_closing_time - ed_rolled_back).total_seconds() / 60

    if 0 < minutes_remaining < 60:
        delta = timedelta(hours=elapsed_business_hours, minutes=minutes_remaining)
    else:
        delta = timedelta(hours=elapsed_business_hours)
    
    delta_hours = round(float(delta.total_seconds() / 3600), 2)

    return delta_hours
```